# Invalid Predicate When Parsing XCode

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

I'm parsing the xml shown below using ElementTree but getting error `Invalid Predicate` with code.

Basically I'm trying to find the element `connect` that has a particular `pin` attribute name.

XML

```
<deviceset>
<devices>
<device name="">
<connects>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="+15V_DC" pad="7"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="FB" pad="3"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="ICOM" pad="4"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="IN+" pad="5"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="IN-" pad="6"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="OUT_HI" pad="1"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="OUT_LO" pad="9"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="PWRCOM" pad="2"/>
</connects>
</device>
</devices>
</deviceset>
```

PYTHON CODE

```
  # Imports
    import xml.etree as ET
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

    # Open a file sent to the function
    file = open(os.path.join(__location__, file));
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    deviceset = root.find ('deviceset')
    deviceset.find('devices').find('device').find('connects').**findall("./connect[@pin = \"FB\"]")**
```

The problem seems to be the XPATH style path (highlighted above).

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Whether you're in 2.x or 3.x, there's no such function as `xml.etree.parse`. Did you mean `from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET`? On top of that, the code you posted will raise an indentation error before it can even run. Can you please give us actual, runnable code that exhibits your error? That makes it a lot easier to debug.

Comment: Also, there's no way ElementTree is going to give you any such error with this XML, because it will give up parsing it because the `<device>` tag is never closer before it can even get to that part of the code. And, if you fix that, because `<deviceset>` is the actual root note, `root.find('deviceset')` is going to return `None`. And, if you fix that, you'll get a syntax error on that `.**`.

Comment: @abarnert ooh sorry ignore my imports -- I was changing things around and did in fact mean `xml.etree import ElementTree as ET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually know what the problem is, because you haven't shown us your actual data and code, and what you have shown us can't even get far enough to have the problem.

But I think it's the extra spaces in your XPath query. `@pin = "FB"` is not the same as `@pin="FB"`, and can't match anything.

Meanwhile…

There is usually not a good reason to explicitly escape quotes in Python. If you want to use double quotes inside the string, just enclose the string in single quotes, and vice-versa. If you need both, often tripled (single or double) quotes are the answer.

Meanwhile, the reason all I can do is guess is that you haven't provided us either valid XML, or valid code that can get far enough to demonstrate the problem.

- There is no such function as `xml.etree.parse`. There is an `xml.etree.ElementTree.parse`, which is probably what you wanted.
- Haphazardly indenting lines means you'll get an `IndentationError` before anything can even run.
- Your code is incomplete—it relies on a `__location__` that you never set, and imports you never import.
- You have a stray `**` in the middle of the code that will raise a `SyntaxError`.
- The `device` node in your XML is never closed, so there's no way ET can parse the file.
- The `deviceset` node is the root, so `root.find('deviceset')` will return `None`.

Also, if you're trying to debug a 95-character-long line of code, you really should break it up to figure out which part is breaking, and to give you a chance to breakpoint or log the inputs to the part that doesn't work.

Fixing all of that, then the only remaining problem is your incorrect xpath, so I'm assuming the same is true for your real code and data, but there's no way to be sure.

Anyway, here's the fixed-up XML:

```
<deviceset>
<devices>
<device name="">
<connects>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="+15V_DC" pad="7"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="FB" pad="3"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="ICOM" pad="4"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="IN+" pad="5"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="IN-" pad="6"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="OUT_HI" pad="1"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="OUT_LO" pad="9"/>
<connect gate="G$1" pin="PWRCOM" pad="2"/>
</connects></device>
</devices>
</deviceset>'''
```

… and code:

```
import os.path
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

file = open('foo.xml')
tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()
deviceset = root
connects = deviceset.find('devices').find('device').find('connects')
# Here we could print out stuff about connects to find out what's wrong.
nodes = connects.findall("./connect[@pin='FB']")
print(nodes[0].get('gate'))
```

When run, it prints:

```
G$1
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting the error at line `nodes = connects.findall("./connect[@pin = 'FB']")` .... `connects` prints out perfectly fine.

Comment: And sorry, I was pasting snippets for the purpose of brevity and made some errors along the way. The `**` syntax was there by SO when I bolded the area causing the problem.

Comment: @user1328021: Posting snippets is good, but don't make them up on the fly while editing. That makes it impossible to tell which problem is your actual problem, and which problems were new errors made along the way. Create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and run it locally to make sure it demonstrates your problem, then post it here. (Also, don't try to apply formatting to code; it breaks the code.)

Comment: @user1328021: As for your new problem… take the spaces out.

Comment: Thank you! This was my problem from the beginning -- the spaces. Thank you for your help and will next time create a SSCCE.